# How to set phone to silent mode using Cordova or Phonegap?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

I want to set my android phone to silent mode using one of my own app which is in phonegap. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first import javascriptinterface package in mainActivity class

```
    import android.webkit.JavascriptInterface;
```

After that add JavaScript interface in onCreate method in the MainActivity Class

```
    super.appView.addJavascriptInterface(new JSInterface(), "sampleproj");
```

Then define the javascript Interface

```
    public class JSInterface{
       @JavascriptInterface
       public void gotoSilent(){
           AudioManager audMangr;
           audMangr= (AudioManager) getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
           audMangr.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
       }
    }
```

Add a permission in AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"/>
```

Now call the native method in javascript

```
    window.sampleproj.gotoSilent();
```

Comment: This appears to no longer work. Causes a Java compile error.