# Activating/deactivating silent mode on android

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a simple if/else code for silent mode on android between two time intervals.

```
 <script>
    var today = new Date();

    var time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
  </script>

const silentOn = (time < 8);
if (silentOn) { console.log('Time is between 00:00 and 08:00') }
else { console.log('Time is between 08:00 and 23:59') }
```

So far my code gives the correct string message to console between the time intervals.
But I want to make it activate/deactive silent mode on android, is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, as if it was it would raise a security concern. Imagine yourself listening to music and surfing a website that changes the volume of your device. Does it make sense?

However, if you are intending to do this from within a web application (such as a Cordova app) then this can be done using plugins that communicate with the native functionality of the device.

Comment: It makes sense, I'll try it out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29004654/how-to-set-phone-to-silent-mode-using-cordova-or-phonegap

Comment: I mean it doesn't make sense when it is done from a webpage you open with your browser. If your question is about how to do it in a Cordova app, then tag it with [tag:cordova].